# Не приходит первый запрос с заголовком от браузера

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

Задача следующего плана: прикрутить SSL к серверу на С/С++. К этом серверу должен для начала (для теста) подключаться клиент (браузер, websocket, javascript, протокол wss, "wss://127.0.0.1:15005"). В качестве примера использую код сервера, ниже расположенный. Но, к сожалению, не приходит в него первый запрос с заголовком от браузера. В чем может быть причина?Вероятно, я чего-то недопонимаю в работе с SSL (хотя с азами ознакомился).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h> 
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int OpenListener ( int port )
{
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    sd = socket ( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    memset ( &addr, '\0', sizeof( addr ) );
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons ( port );
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if ( bind ( sd, ( struct sockaddr* )&addr, sizeof( addr ) ) != 0 )
    {
        perror ( "can't bind port" );
        abort ( );
    }
    if ( listen ( sd, 10 ) != 0 )
    {
        perror ( "Can't configure listening port" );
        abort ( );
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX ( void )
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms ( );  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings ( );   /* load all error messages */
    method = SSLv23_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new ( method );   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp ( stderr );
        abort ( );
    }
    return ctx;
}

void LoadCertificates ( SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile )
{
    /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file ( ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM ) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp ( stderr );
        abort ( );
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file ( ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM ) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp ( stderr );
        abort ( );
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key ( ctx ) )
    {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n" );
        abort ( );
    }
}

void ShowCerts ( SSL* ssl )
{
    X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate ( ssl ); /* Get certificates (if available) */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf ( "Server certificates:\n" );
        line = X509_NAME_oneline ( X509_get_subject_name ( cert ), 0, 0 );
        printf ( "Subject: %s\n", line );
        free ( line );
        line = X509_NAME_oneline ( X509_get_issuer_name ( cert ), 0, 0 );
        printf ( "Issuer: %s\n", line );
        free ( line );
        X509_free ( cert );
    }
    else
        printf ( "No certificates.\n" );
}

void Servlet ( SSL* ssl ) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{
    char buf [ 1024 ];
    char reply [ 1024 ];
    int sd, bytes;

    if ( SSL_accept ( ssl ) == -1 )     /* do SSL-protocol accept */
        ERR_print_errors_fp ( stderr );
    else
    {
        ShowCerts ( ssl );        /* get any certificates */
        bytes = SSL_read ( ssl, buf, sizeof( buf ) ); /* get request */
        if ( bytes > 0 )
        {
            buf [ bytes ] = 0;
            printf ( "Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf );
            SSL_write ( ssl, reply, strlen ( reply ) ); /* send reply */
        }
        else
            ERR_print_errors_fp ( stderr );
    }
    sd = SSL_get_fd ( ssl );       /* get socket connection */
    SSL_free ( ssl );         /* release SSL state */
    close ( sd );          /* close connection */
}

int main ()
{
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL_library_init ( );
    ctx = InitServerCTX ( );        /* initialize SSL */
    char sert[] = "ca-cert.pem";
    LoadCertificates ( ctx, sert, sert ); /* load certs */
    server = OpenListener ( 15005 );    /* create server socket */
    while ( 1 )
    {
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof( addr );
        SSL *ssl;
        int client = accept ( server, ( struct sockaddr* )&addr, (socklen_t*)&len );  /* accept connection as usual */
        printf ( "Connection: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa ( addr.sin_addr ), ntohs ( addr.sin_port ) );
        ssl = SSL_new ( ctx );              /* get new SSL state with context */
        SSL_set_fd ( ssl, client );      /* set connection socket to SSL state */
        Servlet ( ssl );         /* service connection */
    }
    close ( server );          /* close server socket */
    SSL_CTX_free ( ctx );         /* release context */
}
```

Comment: Браузеры на стадии проверки сертификатов часто открывают два соединения. А вы одновременно можете работать только с одним. Но первый коннект вы должны увидеть в принципе. посмотрите до какой стадии доходит коннект. происходит ли accept ... Поставьте `SSL_set_info_callback` распечатайте в нем отладночную информацию по ходу рукопожатия

Comment: @Abyx, спасибо за совет. Но я не сторонник boost, даже скорее наоборот. Пусть он потиху перкочевывает в С++, и я его буду уже "принимать" в стандартизированном, так сказать, виде. Что же касается готовых решений в целом, то я ими пользуюсь, но 1) предпочитаю все-таки как минимум разобраться предварительно в их работе; 2) предпочитаю прозрачный код. А действительно хороших готовых решений не так уж и много. Кстати, разве openssl не готовое решение?

Comment: @Mike, Accept проходит. И да, если подключаться из браузера (https://localhost:15005), то там идет попытка даже не двух, а четырех соединений, но в итоге GET запрос приходит. А вот с websocket такого нет.

Comment: А сертификат браузер признает ? может у websocket проблемы с недостоверными сертификатами ...

Comment: @Mike, понятное дело, что сертификат ненастоящий, но почему тогда проблемы только у websocket? А у обычного https проблем как бы и нет.

Comment: @MaxZS А обычный https у вас спрашивал подтверждение перехода ? Если да - то ответ напрашивается что websocket не может никак спросить разрешения, т.к. работает в фоне и решает не переходить. Попробуйте добавить сертификат в хранилище доверенных в браузере

Comment: @Mike, Да. спрашивал. Возможно, в этом есть мысль. Надо проверить. Но тогда встает вопрос, а можно ли также сделать подтверждение для websocket? Вроде в javascript такого ничего нет.

Comment: @Mike, Импорт сертификата в браузер не принес желаемого результата.